# Excel 2019: Copy data from sheet2 columns B, C, D to sheet1 columns B, C, D based on value of sheet1 column A

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2019

I have the following conditions:

1. I have a Workbook with 2 WorkSheets named Data and Users
2. In Data, I have column A populated with numbers ranging from 1 to 9999999
3. In Users, I have column A populated with numbers ranging form 1 to 9999999
4. In Users, I have multiple rows of each of the numbers (example 10 rows of 1, 18 rows of 2, 32 rows of 3, etc.)
5. In Data, cells B, C and D are empty
6. In Users, cells B, C and D contain email, first name, last name

What I am trying to do is to copy Users : B, C and D values to Data : B, C and D empty cells.

I'm trying to use the INDEX and MATCH functions, but cannot get it to run - continually getting errors.

Here is an example of what I've tried in a test cell in my Users sheet:

```
=INDEX(Users!A:A,MATCH(1,(A2=Data!:A:A),0))
```

So, to clarify.
I have:

Users sheet:

```
A     B          C     D

1     me@me.com  First Last
```

Data sheet:

```
A     B          C     D    
1    
1    
1    
1
```

My objective is to populate every row in Data with the values of Users B, C and D whenever the value in column A matches.

The end result would look like:

Data sheet:

```
A     B          C     D
1     me@me.com  First Last
1     me@me.com  First Last
1     me@me.com  First Last
1     me@me.com  First Last
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just `=INDEX(Users!A:D,MATCH(A2,Users!:A:A,0),column())`?

Comment: Are there different users per number?